# How to find all the continuous functions satisfying an equation?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, real-numbers, functional-equations

The problem that I want to solve is:

"find all the continuous functions $f\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ such that for every $x$, $f(f(f(x))) = x $ , I know that f(x) = x is an answer but how can one find (and prove) all the continuous answers ?
And more generally what are the steps to find similar problems ?

Comment: This problem has plenty of duplicates already, I just link one but I encourages you to look at the linked topics for there are many ideas to pick up.

Comment: In those problems there is usually one answer which is given and it should be proven that it is continuous and satisfies the equation but how do we show all the answers ?

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $d \ge 2$,
let
$f(x) = ax^d+g(x)$
with degree of $g \lt d$.
Then
$f(f(x))
=a(ax^d+g(x))^d+g(ax^d+g(x))
=a(a^dx^{d^2}+...)+g(ax^d+g(x))
$
so
$degree(f(f(x)) = d^2$
(leading term is
$a^dx^{d^2}$)
and
$degree(f(f(f(x))))
=d^3$
so  $f$ can not be
a polynomial of degree $\ge 2$.

If $f(x) = ax+b$
then
$f(f(x))
=a(ax+b)+b
=a^2x+ab+b
$
and
$f(f(f(x)))
=a(a^2x+ab+b)+b
=a^3x+a^2b+ab+b
$
so
$a^3 = 1$
and
$a^2b+ab +b= 0$.

If $b = 0$
then
$a^3 = 1$
which has
one real and 
two complex solutions.

If
$b \ne 0$
then
$0
=a^2+a+1
$
so 
$a
=\dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt{-3}}{2}
=a_1, a_2
$.

Therefore solutions are
$f(x) = ax$
with $a^3 = 1$
(so $a = 1, a_1, a_2$) and,
for any $b$,
$f(x) = a_{1, 2}x+b
$.

So,
if the solution has to be
a polynomial with real coefficients,
it can only be $f(x) = x$.

Comment: I may have missed something, but this seems to assume $f$ is linear without justification?

Comment: Yep. Just seeing what happens in the simplest case.

Comment: Added elimination of higher degree polynomials.

Comment: How do we know that the functions are only polynomial?

Comment: We don't. But I have eliminated them as a possible class.

Comment: What I want to say is that “all continuous functions” seems a vague expression for me. Do we even know all continuous functions to claim that ? Like we know polynomials, exponentials etc what about other functions ?

Comment: What about the nonlinear case ?

Comment: Isn’t the problem too broad ? Without specifying which kind of functions it wants ?